# Tcl: spaces in command substitution

Tags: tcl, substitution

I have a function which outputs a string with or without spaces.
I want to set a variable to the function output. I use the following command:

```
set name [get_name_function object]
```

The problem is that if object name contains spaces (i.e. name with spaces), the whole name is putted in curly braces (name is equal to {name with spaces}).
How can I get the correct name?

Comment: can you show us the definition of `get_name_function`?

Comment: get_name_function is external function, defined outside of tcl

Comment: your question is a bit unclear. Are you saying that `get_name_function` is returning a string with curly braces in it? What is `object`? Is it supposed to be a string, or a list?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `get_name_function` is returning a Tcl list, not a string. You might want to use

```
set name [join [get_name_function object] " "]
```